# How to proxy cookie authentication to an internal API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I use MS identity for a simple authentication using a cookie and username/password method. It's an MVC app where everything is wired up using standard MS Identity AddAuthentication + AddCookie. On successful authentication, I also add some custom claims which are then stored in the encrypted session cookie.

Now, this MVC app also calls another internal API of ours. What I would like to have is to be able to pass the authentication cookie from the MVC app to the internal API and be able to resolve those claims and user identity within the internal API. Keep in mind that it is not mandatory for the internal API to have this data as it works fine for majority of things even without the user being logged in. We use apikey as the security mechanism between MVC app and this internal API which is not open to the world.

We are not using and don't want to use any external identity provider.

Yes, I could manually parse claims and then add them as headers, etc, but I feel it's ugly and may also break due to long claim names.

Is there a more elegant way for this downstream proxying of auth session?

Comment: you could try using the token-based approach like JWT tokens for the internal API. make sure you you have code which prevent unauthorized access. to achieve your requirement generate JWT token in MVC App and pass token to Internal API. after passing validate this JTW token.

Comment: I guess that's what I'll have to do as I don't want to mess too much with high level auth as apikey authentication is already set up using MS identity.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge, There are two ways to achieve this,

1. **Cookie Forwarding**
   I don't like this approach to your MVC app and internal API will be tightly coupled, with this approach
2. **Token Exchange**
   You can generate a JWT token with required claims and pass it into API. This way you will able to decouple the MVC app and API.